# What is going to be the future for Lubuntu (LXQt or LXDE)?

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-environments, lxde, lxqt

I heard that the Lubuntu team is planning to move to LXQt for the default Lubuntu desktop. Is that true? Will it happen on the next point release of 18.04 or on 18.10's (Cosmic Cuttlefish) release? I'd really like to test it.

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/lubuntu-no-more-old-distro/

Comment: https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-development-newsletter-11/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first Lubuntu release with the LXQt desktop environment by default will be Lubuntu 18.10, due for release on October 18, 2018. The first daily build is now available for testing on both 64-bit and 32-bit architectures.<sup>[source](https://news.softpedia.com/news/hands-on-with-first-lubuntu-18-10-build-featuring-the-lxqt-desktop-by-default-521200.shtml)</sup>

[image]
<sup>**Lubuntu 18.10 with the LXQt desktop environment**  (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

[image]
<sup>**Lubuntu 22.04 with the LXQt desktop environment**  (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it's going to be released for 18.04.2?

Comment: No, 18.10 as the answer said.

Comment: Nice 21st birthday present for me...

Comment: Happy birthday.

Comment: Update: we've officially made the switch. You can download it at https://lubuntu.me/downloads